# What will be the probability of the sum of n random numbers to be greater than X?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I want to figure out a way/formula by which I can compute the probability of the sum of $n$ random numbers to be greater than $X$. All the random numbers fall in the range of $[-1000 , -1.01]\cup \{0\}\cup [1.01,1000]$ and step size is $0.01$

Each random number is chosen independently.

**Use Case:** I am working on the development project of a gaming engine. For each round a player is awarded a random score in the range of $[-1000 , -1.01]\cup \{0\}\cup [1.01,1000]$. In the beginning, player can make a bet that after n rounds of the play the total sum of his score will be X. I just want to get the probability of the accuracy of his bet.

**Current Progress -** I was able to somehow get the results using brute force approach (*n rolling dice problem*), however the brute force method is taking lots of computation power. I want an efficient formulae/solution (in terms of computation)

I don't know if Convolutions is the right approach for it.

Thanks for the help, in advance!

Comment: I do not understand the "step size". Integers will never have a decimal after them. Random integers will never have a decimal, either. Are you sure you are looking for integers?

Comment: Could it be that you are not referring to integers, but rather to numbers with at most 2 decimals?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe updated the question.

Comment: @David Yes correct! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is the distribution uniform? Are the random numbers chosen independently? Or is each number distinct?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Yes, the numbers are chosen independently.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, I updated the question with the use case and my current progress. Please check if you could help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other than brute force calculation, I don't think that there is another way to calculate the probability exactly (I could be wrong). But there is a very simple way to obtain a good upper bound to it. I will provide an approximate solution to your problem. If the issue is computational and you don't care about an exact solution, then this will be helpful.

If $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are iid random variables such that $P(Y_i\in[a,b])=1$, then by [Hoeffding inequality](http://cs229.stanford.edu/extra-notes/hoeffding.pdf), for $t>0$,
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-E[Y_i])\geq t\right)\leq \exp\left(\dfrac{-2t^2}{n(b-a)}\right).
$$
In your case, if $Y_i\in[-1000,1000]$ uniformly (or for any symmetric distribution), we have that $E[Y_i]=0$ and 
$$
P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\geq t\right)\leq \exp\left(\dfrac{-t^2/n}{1000}\right).
$$
(Note that this only works for $t>0$.)